# calling variables in a list within for loop

Tags: python, for-loop

I have a list of variables that I want to convert into numbers instead of k, M, B, etc. if statement looks fine, but I don't know how to call the results from the list.

```
A = '1.23k'
B = '2.34k'

items = [A, B]
d = {'k': 3, 'M': 6}

for item in items:
    item = str(item)
    if item[-1] in d:
        num, magnitude = item[:-1], item[-1]
        item = float(num) * 10 ** d[magnitude]
    else:
        item = float(item)
A = items[0]
B = items[1]
```

I thought I could later refer to A and B like above, but it seems that the `item` never links back to A and B after each for loop. (I thought it wasn't difficult but I got stuck totally.)

How would you do it? Thanks.

Update: I might have C, D, E, and so on adding to the list later.

Comment: `A = 1.23k` is not python code.

Comment: @StephenRauch No it's not. Just some numbers given for this example. Sorry for misleading you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you store the updated value in `item`, you're not changing what the corresponding location in the list is pointing to. You're only changing what the variable `item` is pointing to. If you want to change the value in the list, you need to use a range-based for loop and index into the list. That way, you're updating the value stored in the list:

```
A = 1.23k
B = 2.34k

items = [A, B]
d = {'k': 3, 'M': 6}

for i in range(len(items)):
    item = str(items[i])
    if item[-1] in d:
        num, magnitude = item[:-1], item[-1]
        items[i] = float(num) * 10 ** d[magnitude]
    else:
        items[i] = float(item)
A = items[0]
B = items[1]
```

Comment: It's well explained. Thank you.

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Is this better? I was trying to get at the idea that it's not functioning like, for instance, a C++ reference, without getting lost in the woods of Python implementation details, but I agree that it came out misleading.

Comment: Yep. I figured *you* understood, but my biggest gripe was really with saying it is a copy. Trust me, a *lot* of people get tripped up in Python thinking that copies are implicitly made.  Anyway, usually I point people to [here](https://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html) to explain Python semantics. Because really, it's an issue of the Python language, not the implementation

Answer (score 2):

The item in the loop is the local variable and changing it's value will no affect the global items array.
You should infact edit the global items array in the loop,

You can do that quickly by,

```
for i in range(0,len(items)):
```

and replacing item everywhere by

```
items[i]
```

hence you will be changing value of the items variable directly
so finally this loop will do the job

```
for i in range (0,len(items)):
    if item[i][-1] in d:
        num, magnitude = item[i][:-1], item[i][-1]
        item[i] = float(num) * 10 ** d[magnitude]
    else:
        item[i] = float(item[i])
```

Comment: Thank you for your help!